# Inheritance of metaclass

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.x, metaclass

In this well known [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) that explains metaclass in Python. It mentions that the `__metaclass__` attribute will not be inherited.

But as a matter of fact, I tried in Python:

```
class Meta1(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        print "Using Meta1"
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

# "Using Meta1" printed
class Foo1:
    __metaclass__ = Meta1

# "Using Meta1" printed
class Bar1(Foo1):
    pass
```

As expected, both `Foo` and `Bar` use `Meta1` as metaclass and print string as expected.

But in the following sample, when `type(...)` is returned instead of `type.__new__(...)`, the metaclass is no longer inherited:

```
class Meta2(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        print "Using Meta2"
        return type(clsname, bases, dct)

# "Using Meta2" printed
class Foo2:
    __metaclass__ = Meta2

# Nothing printed
class Bar2(Foo2):
    pass
```

Inspecting the `__metaclass__` and `__class__` attributes, I can see:

```
print Foo1.__metaclass__ # <class '__main__.Meta1'>
print Bar1.__metaclass__ # <class '__main__.Meta1'>
print Foo2.__metaclass__ # <class '__main__.Meta2'>
print Bar2.__metaclass__ # <class '__main__.Meta2'>

print Foo1.__class__ # <class '__main__.Meta1'>
print Bar1.__class__ # <class '__main__.Meta1'>
print Foo2.__class__ # <type 'type'>
print Bar2.__class__ # <type 'type'>
```

In conclusion:

1. Both `__metaclass__` and `__class__` **will** be inherited from base class.
2. The creation behavior defined by `Meta2` will be used for `Foo2`, although `Foo2.__class__` is actually `type`.
3. The `__metaclass__` attribute in `Bar2` is `Meta2`, but the creation behavior of `Bar2` is not affected. In another word, `Bar2` uses `type` as its "real" metaclass instead of `Meta2`.

These observations make the inheritance mechanism of `__metaclass__` kind of vague to me.

My guess is that:

1. When directly assigning a class (e.g. `Meta1`) to the `__metaclass__` attribute of another class 'Foo1', It's the `__metaclass__` attribute taking effect.
2. When subclass does not explicitly set `__metaclass__` attribute when defining. The `__class__` attribute instead of `__metaclass__` attribute of base class will decide the "real" metaclass of subclass.

Is my guess correct? How does Python deal with the inheritance of metaclass?

Comment: I think it has to do with type.__new__ and type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608708/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-type-new-in-python

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are speculating a lot, while Python's minimalist and "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules." directive, make it easier to understand than that.

In Python2, a `__metaclass__` attribute in the class body is used at class creation time to call the "class" that class will be. Ordinarily it is the class named `type`. To clarify, that moment is after the parser had parsed the class body, after the compiler had compiled it to a code object, and after it was actually run at program run time, and only if `__metaclass__` is explicitly provided in that class body.

So that let's check way goes in a case like:

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaA

class B(A):
    pass
```

`A` has `__metaclass__` in its body - `MetaA` is called instead of `type` to make it into "class object".
`B` does not have `__metaclass__` in its body. After it is created, if you just try to access the  `__metaclass__` attribute, it is an attribute as anyother, that will be visible because Python willget it from the superclass `A`. If you check `A.__dict__` you will see the  `__metaclass__` and if you check `B.__dict__` don't.

This `A.__metaclass__` attribute is **not used** at all when B is created. If you change it in `A` before declaring `B` will still use the same metaclass as `A` - because Python does use the type of the parent class as metaclass in the absense of the declaration of an explicit `__metaclass__`.

To illustrate:

```
In [1]: class M(type): pass

In [2]: class A(object): __metaclass__ = M

In [3]: print "class: {}, metaclass_attr: {}, metaclass_in_dict: {}, type: {}".format(A.__class__, A.__metaclass__, A.__dict__.get("__metaclass__"), type(A))
class: <class '__main__.M'>, metaclass_attr: <class '__main__.M'>, metaclass_in_dict: <class '__main__.M'>, type: <class '__main__.M'>

In [4]: class B(A): pass

In [5]: print "class: {}, metaclass_attr: {}, metaclass_in_dict: {}, type: {}".format(B.__class__, B.__metaclass__, B.__dict__.get("__metaclass__"), type(B))
class: <class '__main__.M'>, metaclass_attr: <class '__main__.M'>, metaclass_in_dict: None, type: <class '__main__.M'>

In [6]: A.__metaclass__ = type

In [8]: class C(A): pass

In [9]: print "class: {}, metaclass_attr: {}, metaclass_in_dict: {}, type: {}".format(C.__class__, C.__metaclass__, C.__dict__.get("__metaclass__"), type(C))
class: <class '__main__.M'>, metaclass_attr: <type 'type'>, metaclass_in_dict: None, type: <class '__main__.M'>
```

Furthermore, if you try to just create a class through a call to `type` instead of using a body with a `class` statement, `__metaclass__` is also just an ordinary attribute:

```
In [11]: D = type("D", (object,), {"__metaclass__": M})

In [12]: type(D)
type
```

**Summing up thus far**: The `__metaclass__` attribute in Python 2 is only special if it is explicitly placed in the class body declaration, as part of the execution of the `class` block statement.  It is an ordinary attribute with no special properties afterwards.

Python3 both got rid of this strange "`__metaclass__` attribute is no good now", and allowed for further customization of the class body by changing the syntax to specify metaclasses. (It is like declared as if it were a "`metaclass` named parameter" on the `class` statement itself)

Now, to the second part of what raised your doubts: if in the `__new__` method of the metaclass you call `type` instead of  `type.__new__`, there is no way Python can "know" `type` is being called from a derived metaclass. When you call `type.__new__`, you pass as its first parameter the `cls` attribute your metaclass's `__new__` itself  was passed by the runtime: that is what marks the resulting class as being an instance of a subclass of `type`. *That is just like  inheritance works for any other class in Python* - so "no special behaviors" here:

So, spot the difference:

```
class M1(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
         cls = type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)
         # cls now is an instance of "M1"
         ...
         return cls


class M2(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
         cls = type(name, bases, attrs)
         # Type does not "know" it was called from within "M2"
         # cls is an ordinary instance of "type"
         ...
         return cls
```

It can be seen in the interactive prompt:

```
In [13]: class M2(type):
   ....:     def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
   ....:         return type(name, bases, attrs)
   ....:     

In [14]: class A(M2): pass

In [15]: type(A)
Out[15]: type

In [16]: class A(M2): __metaclass__ = M2

In [17]: A.__class__, A.__metaclass__
Out[17]: (type, __main__.M2)
```

(Note that the metaclass `__new__` method first parameter is the metaclass itself, therefore more properly named `metacls` than `cls` as in your code, and in a lot of code "in the wild")