# What Type do I use for SQLalchemy declarative_base?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-typing

I would like to use a Type for my SQLAlchemy base classes, but can't seem to find the type definitions.

Eg:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column, Index
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id_user = Column(
        BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False, index=True
    )
    username = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
```

Now when referencing this User class, I don't know what type to use. Furthermore, If I wanted to have a dictionary which contains table_name : model mapping like:

```
from typing import Any, Dict

table_model_map: Dict[str, Any] = {
    "users": User,
    "another_table": AnotherTableModel,
}
```

How would I go about defining the types for this Dict

Thank you very much for helping me understand this!

Answer (score 5):

Ilja is right in that if all your model classes subclass `Base`, this is a suitable option for type hinting your dict.

If, however, you wanted to type hint something that receives `Base` as an argument, before you have created it, i.e. something like the following:

```py
class DatabaseJanitor:
    def __init__(self, base: WhatTypeHere?, engine):
        self._base = base
        self._engine = engine

    def create_metadata(self):
        self._base.metadata.create_all(self._engine)
```

That is a bit more tricky... I did some digging and this is what I found for `sqlalchemy-1.4.17`.

The following can be seen in `sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py`:

```py
class DeclarativeMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_, **kw):
        ...

def declarative_base(
    ...
    metaclass=DeclarativeMeta,
):
    ...
    return registry(
        _bind=bind,
        metadata=metadata,
        class_registry=class_registry,
        constructor=constructor,
    ).generate_base(
        mapper=mapper,
        cls=cls,
        name=name,
        metaclass=metaclass,
    )

class registry(object):
    ...
    def generate_base(
        ...
        metaclass=DeclarativeMeta,
    ):
        metadata = self.metadata

        bases = not isinstance(cls, tuple) and (cls,) or cls

        class_dict = dict(registry=self, metadata=metadata)
        if isinstance(cls, type):
            class_dict["__doc__"] = cls.__doc__

        if self.constructor:
            class_dict["__init__"] = self.constructor

        class_dict["__abstract__"] = True
        if mapper:
            class_dict["__mapper_cls__"] = mapper

        return metaclass(name, bases, class_dict)
```

So `declarative_base` will return an instance of the `metaclass` keyword argument passed in. So `Base = declarative_base(metaclass=MyNewMetaclass)` will result in `type(Base) == MyNewMetaclass`.

Furthermore, as you can see in `registry.generate_base`, all the attributes for the new instance of the metaclass (such as `metadata`) are contained in `class_dict`. These are implicitly added as attributes to the instance during creation, so they are not available during type hinting.

(Side note: I did a bit of research and it appears that because `DeclarativeMeta` subclasses `type`, `type.__new__` is implicitly called which then adds the values in the `class_dict` dictionary as attributes to the instance of `DeclarativeMeta`. I'll link some resources for further reading at the end of this answer.)

So even if you type hint your function like so:

```py
class DatabaseJanitor:
    def __init__(self, base: DeclarativeMeta, engine):
        self._base = base
        self._engine = engine

    def create_metadata(self):
        self._base.metadata.create_all(self._engine)
```

In `create_metadata`, your type hinting will warn
`Unresolved attribute reference 'metadata' for class 'DeclarativeMeta'`.

So there's not really a good way to type hint `declarative_base` properly. My approach would be to just add it to the docstring for now.

Hope this helps for any future readers! :)

Here's some further reading on type/ metaclasses:

- [SqlAlchemy metaclass confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664385/sqlalchemy-metaclass-confusion)
- [What is the difference between type and type.__new__ in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608708/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-type-new-in-python)
- [Understanding Object Instantiation and Metaclasses in Python](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/python-instantiation-metaclass/)

Comment: We can just do `type(declarative_base())` and it will point to `sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api.DeclarativeMeta`. But unfortunately it does not have proper type hint as you said.

Comment: This is very extensive and well written. Even though I'm disappointed with the outcome, you saved an hour of trying to understand the library's code (which is quite confusing).

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/9a8d039716068ded890e726ba344620907d86170/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py#L1183-L1189) the `generate_base()` function uses [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) as the `metaclass` type and return type, with a default value [`DeclarativeMeta`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/9a8d039716068ded890e726ba344620907d86170/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py#L161-L163). I wonder if a more constrained [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) would be useful here?

Answer (score 2):

`Base` is a type that all your models (that are also types) inherit from, so

```
Dict[str, Base]
```