# Behavior of __new__ in a metaclass (also in context of inheritance)

Tags: python, metaclass

Ok, obviously `__new__` in a metaclass runs when an instance of the metaclass i.e. a class object is instantiated, so `__new__` in a metaclass provides a hook to intercept events (/code that runs) at class definition time (e.g. validating/enforcing rules for class attributes such as methods etc.).

Many online examples of `__new__` in a metaclass return an instance of the type constructor from `__new__`, which seems a bit problematic since this blocks `__init__` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__): "If `__new__()` does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked").

While tinkering with return values of `__new__` in a metaclass I came across some somewhat strange cases which I do not fully understand, e.g.:

```
class Meta(type):
    
    def __new__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        print("Meta __new__ running!")
        # return type(name, bases, attrs)                     # 1. 
        # return super().__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)    # 2.
        # return super().__new__(name, bases, attrs)          # 3.  
        # return super().__new__(type, name, bases, attrs)    # 4. 
        # return self(name, bases, attrs)                     # 5.

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Meta __init__ running!")
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
class Cls(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

1. This is often seen in examples and generally works, but blocks `__init__`
2. This works and `__init__` also fires; but why pass self to a super() call? Shouldn't self/cls get passed automatically with super()?
3. This throws a somewhat strange error I can't really make sense of: TypeError: `type.__new__(X)`: X is not a type object (str); what is X? shouldn't self be auto-passed?
4. The error of 3. inspired me to play with the first arg of the super() call, so I tried to pass type directly; this also blocks `__init__`. What is happening here?
5. tried just for fun; this leads to a RecursionError

Also especially cases 1. and 2. appear to have quite profound implications for inheriting from classes bound to metaclasses:

```
class LowerCaseEnforcer(type):
    """ Allows only lower case names as class attributes! """

    def __new__(self, name, bases, attrs): 
        for name in attrs:
            if name.lower() != name:
                raise TypeError(f"Inappropriate method name: {name}")
            
        # return type(name, bases, attrs)                    # 1.
        # return super().__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)   # 2.

    class Super(metaclass=LowerCaseEnforcer):
        pass
    
    class Sub(Super):
        
        def some_method(self):
            pass
    
        ## this will error in case 2 but not case 1
        def Another_method(self):
            pass
```

1. expected behavior: metaclass is bound to superclass, but not to subclass
2. binds the superclass /and/ subclasses to the metaclass; ?

I would much appreciate if someone could slowly and kindly explain what exactly is going on in the above examples! :D

Answer (score 6):

It is simpler than what you got too.

As you have noted, the correct thing to do is your `2` above:

```
return super().__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)    # 2.
```

Here it goes: `__new__` is a special method - although in certain documentations, even part of the official documentation, it is described as being a `classmethod`, it is not quite so: it, as an object, behaves more like a static method - in a sense that Python does not automatically fill the first parameter when one calls `MyClass.__new__()` - i.e., you'd have to call `MyClass.__new__(MyClass)` for it to work. (I am a step back here - this info applies to all classes: metaclasses and ordinary classes).

When you call `MyClass()` to create a new instance, then Python will call `MyClass.__new__` and insert the `cls` parameter as first parameter.

With metaclasses, the call to create a new instance of the metaclass is triggered by the execution of the `class` statement and its class body. Likewise, Python fills in the first parameter to `Metaclass.__new__`, passing the metaclass itself.

When you call `super().__new__` from within your metaclass' `__new__` you are in the same case of one calling `__new__` manually: the parameter specifying which class' that `__new__` should apply have to be  explicitly filled.

Now, what is confusing you is that you are writting the first parameter to `__new__` as `self` - which would be correct if it were an instance of the metaclass (i.e. an ordinary class). As it is, that parameter is a reference to the metaclass itself.

The docs does not inform an official, or recomended name for the first parameter of a metaclass `__new__`, but usually it is something along `mcls, mcs, metaclass, metacls` - to make it different from  `cls` which is the usuall name for the first parameter of a non-metaclass `__new__` method. In a metaclass, the "class" - `cls` is what is created by the ultimate call to `type.__new__` (either hardcoded, or using `super()`) the return of it is the new-born class (it can be further modified in the `__new__` method after the call to the superclass)  - and when returned, the call to `__init__` takes place normally.

So, I will just comment further the use of trying to call `type(name, bases, namespace)` instead of `type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)`: the first form will just create a plain class, as if the metaclass had not been used at all - (lines in the metaclass `__new__` that modify the namespace or bases, of course, have their effect. But the resulting class will have `type` as its metaclass, and subclasses of it won't call the metaclass at all.  (For the record, it works as a "pre-class decorator" - which can act on class parameters before it is created, and it could even be an ordinary function, instead of a class with a `__new__` method - the call to `type` is what will create the new class after all)

A simple way to check if the metaclass is "bound" to your class is to check its type with `type(MyClass)` or `MyClass.__class__` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I finally figured out what the problem was and summarized it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67297367/6455731

Answer (score 3):

I think I finally figured this out (somewhat), my initial confusion can mainly be ascribed to my failure to realize that

1. there is a difference between `object.__new__` and `type.__new__`
2. there is a difference between returning `type()` and returning `super().__new__` from a metaclass

Discussion of these two points should clear up my initial example as well as the seemingly enigmatic inheritance behavior.

**1. The difference between `object.__new__` and `type.__new__`**

First a few words concerning `__new__`.
The [documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is imo pretty clear on this, but I'd still like to add and/or emphasize some things:

- `__new__` can be understood as a special cased static method that takes `cls` as first parameter and passes the remaining parameters (most often `*args, **kwargs`) to `__init__`.
  _ `__new__` and `__init__` are invoked successively (actually by the metaclass's `__call__`!), whereby `__init__` is only invoked if `__new__` returns an instance of `cls`.
- `__new__` takes a single *argument* (this is about calling `__new__`, not defining/overloading it) i.e. `cls` and returns an instance of that class.

An important thing that eluded me at first is that there is a difference between `object.__new__` and `type.__new__`.
I discovered this while I was playing with `__new__`'s parameters/arguments; take a look at these 'instructive errors':

```
class ObjNewExample:
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # return super().__new__(cls)                      # correct 
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)       # instructive error

    def __init__(self, some_attr):
        self._some_attr = some_attr

one = ObjNewExample(42)

class TypeNewExample(type):
    
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        # return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)  # correct
        return super().__new__(mcls)                        # instructive error

# class Cls(metaclass=TypeNewExample):
#     pass
```

ObjNewexample with `return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` throws something like

- `TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)`,
  while TypeNewexample with `return super().__new__(mcls)` throws
- `TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments`,
  which shows that `object.__new__` and `type.__new__` are quite different methods!

Also: consider the difference between parameters and arguments with `__new__`:

- `object.__new__` takes `cls, *args, **kwargs` as parameters, but requires only `cls` as argument (`*args, **kwargs` get passed to `__init__`)
- `type.__new__` takes `mcls, name, bases, attrs` as parameters *and* arguments

**The difference between returning `type()` and returning `super().__new__` from a metaclass**

The main problem with the example I initially posted however is the difference between returning `type()` and returning `super().__new__` from a metaclass's `__new__` (which is embarrassingly obvious now..). (See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608708/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-type-new-in-python))

- returning `type(name, bases, attrs)` from `mcls`: creates an instance of `type`
- returning `super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)` from `mcls`: creates an instance of the actual metaclass (which is derived from `type`),
  which also explains why `__init__` is inhibited in case 1 but not case 2 of the initial example! (Remember: `__init__` does not get invoked if `__new__` returns anything but an instance if `__new__`'s first parameter i.e. (m)cls)

This should be instructive:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        
        # this creates an intance of type (the default metaclass)
        # This should be eql to super().__new__(type, name, base, attrs)!
        obj1 = type(name, bases, attrs) 
        
        # this creates an instance of the actual custom metaclass (which is derived from type)
        # i.e. it creates an instance of type.__new__'s first arg
        obj2 = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)

        print(isinstance(obj1, mcls))
        print(obj1.__class__)
        print(isinstance(obj2, mcls))
        print(obj2.__class__)
        
class Fun(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

So quickly walking through cases 1-5 from my initial post:

1: returns a new `type` object, that is an instance of `type`, not the actual custom metaclass (derived from `type`), thus `__init__` of the custom metaclass is inhibited; this appears to be actually equivalent to case 4!

2: as @jsbueno pointed out, this is the most likely intended ('correct') behavior: this creates an instance of the actual custom metaclass.

3: this barfs itself because `type.__new__` expects an object of type `type` (the object to be instantiated) as first argument

4: see case 1

5: `self` (probably better named 'cls' or 'mcls') is `Meta`; calling a class in its own constructor is obviously recursive.

The above also provides an explanation for the seemingly weird inheritance behavior of the second snippet from my initial posts!
So why does `Sub`'s definition of `Another_method` error in case 2 of `LowerCaseEnforcer`, but not case 1?

Because in case 1 `Lowercaseenforcer` returns an instance of `type` (not of `LowerCaseEnforcer`!), so `Super` is of type `type` (its metaclass is `type`, not `LowerCaseEnforcer`)! So while `LowerCaseEnforcer.__new__` fires and enforces the lowercase restriction for `Super`, `Super` is just a vanilla class of type `type` and `Sub` is derived from it (with no special effect).

Whereas in case 2 `Super`'s metaclass is of type `LowerCaseEnforcer` and so is `Sub`'s, so `LowerCaseEnforcer.__new__` is involved in the definition of `Sub`.

One thing that is still a bit unclear however is the behavior of static methods in super calls (see also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788214/super-and-staticmethod-interaction)).
E.g. why does `super().__new__(cls)` work? Shouldn't this be `super(cls, cls).__new__(cls)` (or something like that)?
But I guess this is another (interesting) topic! :D